# In category page move the category image to top after header

Tags: magento-1.9, category, page

I want to display the category image in top of category page just after the header.Currently it is showing in `2colums-left.phtml` right side container.I don't want to change the layout but just the image alone need to be displayed on top..

Comment: Which Magento Version?

Comment: The version is Magento 1.9

Answer (score 2):

Open

app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/catalog/category/view.phtml

and delete or comment out

```
if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
    $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
    $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
}
```

This will prevent the image from showing twice.

Then open

app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/page/2colums-left.phtml

after `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>`

add

```
    <?php if ($current_category =  Mage::registry('current_category')):?>
        <?php if ($current_category->getImageUrl()):?>
            <?php echo '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$current_category->getImageUrl().'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($current_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($current_category->getName()).'" /></p>';?>
        <?php endif?>
    <?php endif?>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to add a new reference for 2columns-left layout pages. To do so, please follow these steps:

> Name the structural block

Open the file layout/page.xml in your active theme folder. Inside you will find lines like:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="left" as="left"/>
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content"/>
<block type="core/text_list" name="right" as="right"/>
```

Add a new line somewhere inside the same block tag.

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="newreference" as="newreference"/>
```

> Tell Magento where to place it

Since we want the new structural block to appear only on pages that use 2-column-left.phtml, open this file in the current theme.

Since we want to place the **newreference** block to be placed just below header. In this case our updated code should look like:

```
<div class="main-container col2-left-layout">
   <div><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newreference') ?></div>
   <div class="main">
      <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
      <div class="col-main">
         <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
         <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
   </div>
```

> Populating structural block

Now let's create new file **app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/newreference.phtml** with the following content:

```
<h1 style="background-color:yellow">Hello New Reference!</h1>
```

Go to appropriate layout XML file (page.xml) and add this block to the appropriate place (for testing purpose you could place it under “default” handle).

```
<reference name="newreference">
   <block type="core/template" name="newReferenceBlock" template="newReference.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Please follow above steps and let me know if it worked.

**PS:** Reference is taken from [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-reference-structural-block/).

Comment: Great explanation. Up-voted :)